# is there a python function for reading multiple images from a folder into a single array

Tags: python, file, opencv, tiff

i am trying to read multiple images from a folder in a single numpy array to feed them to my deep learning model. when i print the shape i get the error message that none type object has no shape. which means that the images were not read by opencv(for jpg)/tifffile(for .tif)My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import tifffile as tiff

filepath1 = "D:/Programs/transnet/dataset/train"
filepath2 = "D:/Programs/transnet/dataset/train_label"
img = np.ndarray((cv.imread(filepath1 + "*.jpg")))
clt = np.ndarray((tiff.imread(filepath2 + "*.tif")))

print(img.shape)
print(clt.shape)
```

I have already tried glob.glob but it doesn't work.
i am expecting a 4 dimensional array of number of rgb images

Comment: `tifffile.imread(filepath2 + '*.tif')` should work. If `train_label` is a directory, use `filepath2 + '/*.tif'`.

Comment: thanks @cgohlke  '/*.tif 'works. train_label is a directory. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work for opencv and jpg

Comment: Why not get all files and open them using the list of files like I did in my answer @AnkitSharma ?

Comment: @ DeveshKumarSingh I need a 4 dimensional numpy array as my output not a list. Can you tell me how to convert this list output to 4 dimentional array. for example the shape should be (n_sample, height, width, n_channel). All the images in the folder are of same size.

Comment: Consider `tifffile.TiffSequence` (you can pass a `imread` function to read JPEG file) or [`pims.ImageSequence`](http://soft-matter.github.io/pims/v0.4.1/image_sequence.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module to do file traversal operations, especially `os.listdir` and `os.path.join` as follows

```
import os

def get_all_images(folder, ext):

    all_files = []
    #Iterate through all files in folder
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        #Get the file extension
        _,  file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        
        #If file is of given extension, get it's full path and append to list
        if ext in file_ext:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
            all_files.append(full_file_path)

    #Get list of all files
    return all_files

filepath1 = "D:/Programs/transnet/dataset/train"
filepath2 = "D:/Programs/transnet/dataset/train_label"

#List of all jps and tif files
jpg_files = get_all_images(filepath1, 'jpg')
tif_files = get_all_images(filepath2, 'tif')
```

Now once you have the list of all files, you can iterate through the list and open the images.

Comment: `if ext in file` will be `True` even if `ext` is part of the filename, but not the actual file extension. Better to use `if ext in os.path.splitext(file)[1]` instead.

Comment: Good point! Updated the code :) Thanks @Safwan Please take a look again and if it looks good, consider upvoting :)

Comment: There is a mistake in the code. I have edited it. You will see it once my edit is peer-reviewed.

Comment: thanks @Safwan. But I need a 4 dimensional array output and not a list(all images are same size).How do i change this code for that

Comment: Given a file path, do you have a function to open it and read it via imread?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes the code i shared works for tif now after modification by cgohlke. But it doesn't work for .jpg using cv2

Comment: What I am saying is that cv.imread and tiff.imread should work to open with single files, where those files comes from the list of files I created! @AnkitSharma